# Python: shortcut conditional expression

Tags: python, conditional-statements, expression, shortcut

the shortcut conditional expression :
`expression1` if `condition` else `expression2`
`x=1 if a>3 else 2`
But: can I have 2 expressions at the start ?
`x=1,b=3 if a>3 else 2`

Thanks to > `idontknow`, solution is >

```
    previousTime,BS_Count=(db_row_to_list[0][14],BS_Count+1) if db_row_to_list[0][14] is not None else (db_row_to_list[0][3],BS_Count)
```

Comment: Why didn't you just try this out yourself?

Comment: Hello ! Can you tell us more about your use case for these expressions? Some context would surely be helpful! 

Comment: Nevermind. I understand your question now 

Comment: @RandomDavis I think it is because it did not work for the OP, and they want to learn how to do something like this .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not quite. For something this, it would be possible to use an if statement.

```py
if a > 3:
    x = 1
    b = 3
else:
    x = 2
    b = None
```

If you want everything to become a oneliner, you can use tuple unpacking in Python. What tuple unpacking does is basically take the elements from a tuple and store them as variables, instead of elements of a tuple.

An application of this concept would be something like this:

```py
x, b = (1, 3) if a > 3 else (2, None)
```

Note that it is a oneliner!

**EDIT:** To answer your question in the updated context:

You can use the following, shorter code. I think the effect will be the same.

```py
a = 3
b = 7
c = 6
a, b = (8, b+1) if c > 3 else (5, b)
print(a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks to those who gave the 'tuple' answer. In my actual code: I wanted to put in a 'count+=1' as the 2nd expression.  I guess this is not possible. I think I could put it in a function though:   `num=doIt() if a>3 else 5`, where inside doIt() I can increment my count.

Comment: @pythonDerby Can you elaborate? What are you trying to do exactly? Does something like this make sense for your context? `points += (100 if answer_correct is True else 0) `

Comment: I've added context below >> (ie. not easy in these comment boxes!)

Comment: @pythonDerby You can always [edit your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65740087/edit) to provide context.

Comment: a, b = (8, b+1) if c > 3 else (5, b), I had tried that but had tried 'b+=1' and when I got an error, I aborted that experiment ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

In your example:

```
x=1 if a>3 else 2
```

The conditional expression part is:

```
1 if a>3 else 2
```

So, you're assigning the result of that conditional expression to `x`.

In your second example, this is invalid syntax:

```
x=1,b=3 if a>3 else 2
```

That's because it's equivalent to:

```
(1,b)=3 if a>3 else 2
```

Or, as a simpler example:

```
(1,b)=3
```

This is invalid syntax, because you can't do something like `1 = 3` in Python, which is what that code is trying to do. Although if both elements of the tuple were not literals, you'd get a different error:

```
(b,a)=3
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

So, if you want to do multiple assignments with a conditional expression, you can have the conditional expression return a tuple, and have your left-hand side be a tuple of the two variables you want to assign values to:

```
x,b=(1, 3) if a>3 else (2, 2)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
if a > 3:
    x = 1
    b = 3
else:
    x = 2
    b = 2
```

Which is what I assume you intended with your original code.

Comment: Cheers, I was trying to put the if-else into a one liner, but I guess in python this isn't possible....yet!    `if db_row_to_list[0][14] is not None:
                    previousTime=db_row_to_list[0][14]
                    BS_Count+=1
                else:
                    db_row_to_list[0][3]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tuples`:

```py
>>> a = 4
>>> (x, b) = (1, 3) if a > 3 else (2, 2)
>>> x
1
>>> b
3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `x = 1, b = 3 if a > 3 else 2` is not valid. You can still have a one-liner though:

```
x, b = 1 if a > 3 else 2, 3 if a > 3 else 2
```

This sets the value of x to `1 if a > 3 else 2` and b to `3 if a > 3 else 2`

Answer (score 0):

For context : This is the actual code >

```
     if db_row_to_list[0][14] is not None:  
        previousTime=db_row_to_list[0][14]    
        BS_Count+=1  
     else:  
        db_row_to_list[0][3]
```

I can do this though : ie. use a function >  but is it any better??

```
     num=3  
     num1=7
     def doIt():
        print("doIt()")
        global num,num1
        num=8
        num1+=1
        return num

     a=6
     num=doIt() if a>3 else 5
     print(num," ",num1)
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on this context.